# Auto map network from Linux drive

Tags: linux, networking, windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-7

So I started working for a company that has a 2003 SBS as the domain controller with the workstations being Windows 7. We have a Linux server with Samba install, which acts like a file server. The current setup has us logging into the workstation as the user and mapping the drive, because we have a single account for the linux server. My question is if anyone know a way for the network drive to auto mount for each of the users, regardless of the Workstation.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you. From:
http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html

```
NET USE linuxserverip
```

Will map the network drive for you.

Create a text file with a .bat file extension, paste that line in there, save it and run it to test it out. Then create a startup script http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753404.aspx to use this script at every login.